# Scene boundary issue when reducing sentinel 1 in natural values vs dB

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, image-segmentation, reducers

I have written a function that smooths sentinel 1 images by reducing across clusters created from a sentinel 2 median image, and then reduces the sentinel 1 collection to the p5 value. When I run the function on dB values it works as expected, but when I use natural values strange things happen at the scene boundaries.

An example is here:

```
// The location of the scene boundary I am looking at
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[25.356019971276755,-15.045220885450785],[25.450433728600974,-15.045220885450785], [25.450433728600974,-15.014549928161024], [25.356019971276755,-15.014549928161024], [25.356019971276755,-15.045220885450785]]);

Map.centerObject(geometry,14);

// Cloud mask the S2 collection and reduce to median
var s2image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2020-03-01','2020-05-01').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 25)
.map(function (img){
  var cloudProb = img.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var scl = img.select('SCL');
  var cloud = cloudProb.gt(0).or(scl.eq(3));
  var mask = cloud.lt(1);
  return img.select(['B4','B3','B2']).updateMask(mask);
}).median().divide(1000);

Map.addLayer(s2image,{max:2},'S2 median',0);

// Compute clusters from the s2 median image
var clusters = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(s2image,25,3).select('clusters');

Map.addLayer(clusters.randomVisualizer(),{},'Clusters',0);

// Filter the s1 collection and convert to natural values
var s1coll_dB = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD').filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2019-03-01','2020-02-28').select('VH');
var s1coll_nat = s1coll_dB.map(function(image){return ee.Image(10.0).pow(image.divide(10.0)).rename('VH')});

// Function to compute the cluster VH means and reduce the collection to p5 value
function  reduceS1(coll){
  var means = coll.map(function getMeans(image){
    var clusterMeans = clusters.addBands(image).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.mean());
    return image.addBands(clusterMeans,['VH'],true);
    
  });
  return means.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([5]));
  
}

Map.addLayer(reduceS1(s1coll_dB),{min:-25,max:-10},'dB');
Map.addLayer(reduceS1(s1coll_nat),{max:0.02},'natural values');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/858b09f6a49e36c00de39d676f7e0d61

Answer (score 0):

I received a great answer to my question from Noel Gorelick on the earth engine developers forum, so wanted to share it here:

*The issue is that you're reducing over the entire cluster image for every input image, regardless of how much they intersect.
So "blank" areas in the inputs come out as zeros in the reduced image.  That means you have the same problem in both collections, but 0 is higher than all the dB input values, so it's at the top of the range there, not the bottom.
First, make sure you're only reducing the relevant area by clipping the cluster image (or applying the input's mask),
and second, get rid of zero values before taking the percentile.  Also a good idea to re-clip after converting from dB to Nat,
since the starting point for that conversion is a global (constant) image.*

https://code.earthengine.google.com/633d1ba2f316ad43f037f68eeadbe12e